# Solution for the integration of rational function with exponential term.

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to integrate following:

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{t+1}e^{-\frac{a t+b}{1-t}}dt$$

Here, $a$ and $b$ are positive constants. I notice that  integrand varies from $1$ to $0$. Since it is a well-bounded region, I am wondering if I can evaluate it.

Does anyone have an idea? Any tight approximation is also fine.

Comment: Are you interested in tight approximations for $a+b\approx 0$ or $a+b$ being very large?

Comment: Actually $b\approx 0$, however, $a\approx 0$ is not the case always. But, as seen the responses to this question, I understood that it is not easy to get an exact expression analytically. So I can rely on your following suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For the integral 
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{t+1}e^{-\frac{a t+b}{1-t}}dt$$
it can be seen that
$$\frac{a t + b}{1-t} = \frac{b+a - a (1-t)}{1-t} = -a + \frac{b+a}{1-t}$$
and
$$I = e^{a} \, \int_{0}^{1} e^{-\frac{a+b}{1-t}} \frac{dt}{1+t}.$$

Now, 
$$\int e^{-p/(1-t)} \, \frac{dt}{1+t} = e^{-p/2} \, Ei\left(\frac{p (t+1)}{2(t-1)}\right) - Ei\left(\frac{p}{t-1} \right),$$
where $Ei(x)$ is the Exponential integral. The difficulty arises when $t=1$ since $Ei(\infty) = \infty$. If the upper limit was not $1$ then this integral would be finite and provide a proper value. As it stands, from this view, the integral cannot be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

$$I(a,b)=e^{-b}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-(a+b)t}}{(1+t)(1+2t)}\,dt  $$
is clearly related to the Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{(1+t)(1+2t)}$ and approximated by

$$ e^{-b}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-(a+b)t} e^{-3t}\left(1+\tfrac{5}{2}t^2\right)\,dt = \frac{5+(3+a+b)^2}{(3+a+b)^3}e^{-b}.$$

Comment: Can you please let me know how you wrote the second integral (approximation)?

Comment: @Frey: I just found a function of the $p(t) e^{-kt}$ kind fitting $\frac{1}{(1+t)(1+2t)}$ nicely in a right neighbourhood of the origin, where most of the mas of the integral is concentrated. Probably the last approximation can be further sharpened by using Cauchy-Schwarz.